# ZipArchive locking file

Tags: vb.net, php-ziparchive

I need to check whether a ZIP is valid and delete it if it's invalid.  Here's my VB.NET code:

```
Try
    Using zip As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(fileName, ZipArchiveMode.Read)
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Log.Error(ex)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    File.Delete(fileName)
End Try
```

My trouble is that the File.Delete fails because the file is still in use.  Is there a way to get ZipArchive to release the file, or a better way to check for bogus ZIP files?

TIA

Comment: You should catch the InvalidDataException not any old exception.  Set a flag in the exception handler and delete if its set outside the catch (when zip has been disposed).

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't make any difference.